# Angular, NG-pluralize with 2 counters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pluralize

I have a challenge, I am building somewhat of a library which containts folders and files, when selecting these I want the proper messages to pop up, like:

1 file and 1 folder selected
-or-
3 files and 2 folders selected

I figured this would be easy with `ng-pluralize`

This is what I have so far:

```
<ng-pluralize count="amountSelected()"
    when="{'0': '',
           'one': '1 file is selected.',
           'other': '{} files are selected.'}">
</ng-pluralize>
```

The `amountSelected()` returns the number of selected files, `folderSelected()` would return the amount of selected folders but I don't know where to place it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Greetings,

Bram

Comment: The function should go into the controller, check the example at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize.

Comment: Did that, works fine now. Thnx!

Comment: I wanted to post the answer just by copying the from there, but I can't take the credit :)